# How to find the equation of a graph of a rational function from a set of points?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

For example, the data points are:

$(1,1)$

$(2,1/2)$

$(3,1/3)$

$(4,1/4)$

$(5,1/5)$

How do I find the equation from those points? Do I look at the common ratio of the y-values or something?

Comment: You might note a mapping of the for $x \mapsto 1/x$, right?

Comment: If it is stated that the datapoints are necesarily that of a rational function of the form 

$$y=\frac{a}{x+b}+c$$ 

you can always find $a$, $b$, and $c$ with $3$ entries, by producing a system of equations of 3 variables and 3 equations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just asking for *a* curve fitting those points, note that each given point $(x,y)$ has the form $\left(x,\frac{1}{x}\right) \Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{x}$. For this particular problem, the problem-solving skill you're using is called *pattern recognition*.

For other problems that ask you to find the curve given a set number of points, you generally need $n+1$ points to determine an equation with degree $n$. If a pattern isn't immediately evident, then you generally need computer software to find the best fit equation.

Comment: OK, I get it now.

Comment: Glad it helped! There should be a check mark on the left side that you can click to accept the answer if this has addressed all your questions.